# Bootstrapping when cashflows are irregular

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bootstrapping

EDIT: this question was previously closed because it was 'assumed that it should be common knowledge'. I advise you to READ THE QUESTION PROPERLY and you will find out is is NOT common knowledge at all, due to the fact this is a particular case of bootstrapping.
In regular bootstrapping you would have a bond and spot rates for all coupon cashflows before it. Here, on the other hand, you have the inverse: a final coupon, for which you don't have the spot rate, and a bond for which you do. Again, read the question properly then give me an explanation, don't come to hasty conclusions: even your certainties may be wrong.

QUESTION:

I have 2 cashflows. One is a zero-coupon bond, the other is a coupon.

```
    t    cashflow   Spot_Rate
0  0.05    101.1       -0.51
1  0.08     0.9         ?
```

How do I calculate spot rate for the second cashflow using the first spot rate?

Thought: Would I have to create a bond which pays (100+0.9) in t=0.08 and a coupon of 0.9 in 0.05 like so?
[image]

This strikes me as strange as - in theory - spot rates wouldn't depend on the entity of the cashflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate spot rate when all you have is a coupon](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/70166/how-to-calculate-spot-rate-when-all-you-have-is-a-coupon)

Comment: If the 0.9%-coupon-bearing bond has cash flow dates 0.05 and 0.08, and if the zero rates are defined as non-annualised rates, and if the second bond trades at par, then your ansatz seems okay.

Comment: Hi Kermitt. Thanks for your answer. No, the second bond is not a bond per-se. It is just a coupon that I stripped, it comes from another bond that has a longer maturity.

Comment: @Snowmate : based on what you have written all we know is how to discount the cashflow at $t=0.05$. There is unfortunately no mathematical principle from which one could derive the discount factor (or a spot rate) for $t=0.08$.

Comment: Hi Kurt. Thank you very much for your answer, and YES, that is what I wanted to know. It is interesting that we don't have a way to do so. Here below are some ways one might find useful to build the curve when relevant bonds are absent: https://fincad.com/resources/resource-library/article/revisiting-art-and-science-curve-building